# HTML5 input required attribute get stucked after first prompt

Tags: html, user-input

Please help.
I use the required attribute of the input tag and whenever an input is not provided, it works normally by emphasizing on the field but after the first prompt, if I enter a value into the field, it just keep prompting me to enter a value even though a value is in the input field already...

```
<input type="text" required autofocus name="username"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with that error? why you use tag python?

Comment: I removed the Python tag already....Thanks

Comment: I created a super minimal fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vcgpjeLh/ where it looks like it is working. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome.... I'm new here, please how do I add error snippet?